# Takes a string array and searches for two words that are anagrams of each other

Tags: java

Looking for some advice on whether or not this can be improved in terms of efficiency and speed, it would need to work on large data sets.

```
public class Anagrams {

    public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {  
    String s1 = str1.replaceAll("\\s", "");  
    String s2 = str2.replaceAll("\\s", "");  
    boolean status = true;  
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {  
        status = false;  
    } else {  
        char[] ArrayS1 = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();  
        char[] ArrayS2 = s2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();  
        Arrays.sort(ArrayS1);  
        Arrays.sort(ArrayS2);  
        status = Arrays.equals(ArrayS1, ArrayS2);  
    }  
    if (status) {  
        return true; 
    } else {  
        return false; 
    }  
    }  


    public static String searchAnagram(String[] array)
    {

        String anagramsList = "";
        Arrays.sort(array, (str1, str2) -> str1.length() - str2.length());
        for(int i=0;i<(array.length -1); i++)
        {
            int j=0;
            while(array[i].length() == array[i+j].length())
            {

                if(isAnagram(array[i],array[i+j]))
                {
                    anagramsList += (array[i] + " " + array[i+j] + ", ");
                    System.out.println(array[i] + " " + array[i+j] + ", ");
                }
                j++;
            }

        }
        if(anagramsList == "")
        {
            anagramsList = "No anagrams foud";
        }
        return anagramsList;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the intention behind `String s1 = str1.replaceAll("\\s", "");`, to remove all whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

In `isAnagram` one should start local variables with a small letter (just a convention).
Do not use if-else to return a boolean.

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    String s1 = str1.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    String s2 = str2.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    boolean status = true;
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        status = false;
    } else {
        char[] arrayS1 = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] arrayS2 = s2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arrayS1);
        Arrays.sort(arrayS2);
        status = Arrays.equals(arrayS1, arrayS2);
    }
    return status;
}
```

However if you think of an anagram as a form of sorted string, one could introduce either a type Anagram, or - here - a function deriving such a sorted string: here `canonicalForm`.

```
public static boolean isAnagram2(String str1, String str2) {
    return canonicalForm(str1).equals(canonicalForm(str2));
}

public static String canonicalForm(String s) {
    String cleaned = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    char[] chars = cleaned.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Most important searching for anagrams can use a map from canonical value to string(s).
For ease of mapping to the original algorithm. the mapped-to value is a concatenation of anagrams:

```
public static String searchAnagram(String[] strings) {
    Map<String, String> canonicalToValue = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : strings) {
        s = s.replace('\t', ' '); // Omit tabs, reserve them for our usage.
        String canonical = canonicalForm(s);
        canonicalToValue.merge(canonical, s, (oldS, s) -> oldS + "\t" + s);
    }
    return canonicalToValue.values().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains('\t'))                
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

I use a tab (`\t`) as it seems that spaces might occur in strings.
One could also use a slash (`" / "`).

Better yet would be to return a `List<String>` of anagrams, and keep a `List<String>` or `Set<String>` as map value. A `TreeSet<String>` would remove duplicates and is sorted.

Instead of `isAnagram` one only needs `canonicalForm` (better `anagramForm`?).

The complexity is reduced in code complexity, faster.
Your attempt to optimize sorting on length is just a partial optimizing, needing extra checks / not fitting entirely. By using a HashMap on the canonical form of a string,
one has exactly an immediate search result.

The solution could give `"malmodera malordema marmelado melodrama, gasometro gasometro somertago"`.

No result *as String* would better be an empty String. Again a `List` seems more usable.

Answer (score 0):

You have used sorting which has a time complexity of O(nlogn)

You can use HashMap ,by which time complexity of program would be reduced to O(n)..Below is the code

```js
static boolean areAnagram(String str1, String str2) 
    { 
  
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap1 
            = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap2 
            = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
  
        char arr1[] = str1.toCharArray(); 
        char arr2[] = str2.toCharArray(); 
  
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
  
            if (hmap1.get(arr1[i]) == null) { 
  
                hmap1.put(arr1[i], 1); 
            } 
            else { 
                Integer c = (int)hmap1.get(arr1[i]); 
                hmap1.put(arr1[i], ++c); 
            } 
        } 
  
        
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) { 
  
            if (hmap2.get(arr2[j]) == null) 
                hmap2.put(arr2[j], 1); 
            else { 
  
                Integer d = (int)hmap2.get(arr2[j]); 
                hmap2.put(arr2[j], ++d); 
            } 
        } 
  
        if (hmap1.equals(hmap2)) 
            return true; 
        else
            return false; 
    }
```

Comment: No need to transform the strings into character arrays, just use the method `charAt()` of `String`. Don't use `get()` twice on the maps. Don't cast to `int` but use `Integer`. Don't repeat code writing to the maps. Don't use `if` at the end, just `return hmap1.equals(hmap2)`.